# My html data entry is not saving in google sheet, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

No data is saved in google sheet from my html form. I'd watch couple of tutorials online and tried different approach but still same result. My google sheet script is showing execution started, execution completed and no error message shows in html javascript script. Hopefully someone can help me on this and explain the root cause and what to do to fix it. I attached the entire html and google sheet script. Thanks.

```
const sheetName = 'Data record'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup(){
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key' , activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e){
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try{
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValue()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch(e){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally{
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Application Monitoring System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form name="google-spreadsheet" method="post">
            <h1>Entry Form</h1>
            <div class="input-box">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Company name" name="company_name" required>
                    <i class='bx bx-building'></i>
                </div>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Position applied" name="position_applied" required>
                        <i class='bx bx-briefcase'></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Source" name="source" required>
                            <i class='bx bx-mobile'></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                        <i class='bx bx-envelope'></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="input-field" name="dropdown">
                        <input type="date" placeholder="Date applied" name="dated_applied" required>
                    </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="dropdown">Status
                        <span class="left-icon"><i class='bx bx-chevrons-down'></i></span>
                        <span class="right-icon"></span>
                        <div class="choices">
                            <a href="#" style="--i:1;"><span name ="status" required></span>Passed</a>
                            <a href="#" style="--i:2;"><span span name ="status" required></span>Failed</a>
                            <a href="#" style="--i:3;"><span span name ="status" required></span>Pending</a>
                            <a href="#" style="--i:4;"><span span name ="status" required></span>Expired</a>
                        </div> <!--==CLASS = CHOICES==-->
                    </div> <!--==CLASS = DROPDOWN==-->
                </div> <!--==CLASS = BOX==-->

                <div class="button-container">
                    <button type="submit" class="button" name="submit">Save</button>
                    <button type="view" class="button" name="view-report">View Report</button>
                </div>
                    <span id="success"></span>
            </div> <!--==CLASS = INPUT-BOX (ALL)==-->
        </form>
    </div> <!--==CLASS = WRAP==-->

    <script>
        const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyw9-TkMWaD_uMVpkPOelDTpKtth5OLTHyoKU6wTZkzlS0H-d9WqM2E2mITP6ZQNnb1/exec'
        const form = document.forms['google-spreadsheet']
      
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
            .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        })
    </script>

<script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From your showing script, it seems that your script depends on the header row of the Google Spreadsheet. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current Spreadsheet from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including your current script?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, I appreciate your respond. The current script for my google sheet is on my previous post. For my spreadsheet, hope, you can access this link  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S8U7IfpBgI-oijTy8g0RB6TdWE8y74uP0Isfg4hSaqc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Database name  = Application Database                                                                                           Spreadsheet name = Data record

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample spreadsheet. I apologize for this situation.